# Code coverage help needed for Messaging.sendEmail

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, code-coverage, singleemailmessage

I have a schedulable class, which sends out 1 email per minute if the record has never been updated by its owner. The problem is that I am able to reach 55% coverage, the entire execute() method and the first 2 rows of sendMail() but nothing else :(
Could somebody provide some guidance what is the problem or how to improve the coverage?

The class:

```
global class SendMarketingMail Implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    try {
        //schedule to run every min
        DateTime currentDateTime = System.now().addMinutes(1);
        String nextScheduleTime = String.valueof(currentDateTime.second()) + ' ' + String.valueof(currentDateTime.minute()) + ' ' + String.valueof(currentDateTime.hour()) + ' ' + String.valueof(currentDateTime.day()) + ' ' + String.valueof(currentDateTime.month()) + ' ? ' + String.valueof(currentDateTime.Year());
        SendMarketingMail m = new SendMarketingMail();
        system.schedule('ApexMarketingEmails at' + System.now().format(), nextScheduleTime, m);
        sendMail();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Boolean expectedExceptionThrown = e.getMessage().contains('already scheduled for execution');
        System.AssertEquals(expectedExceptionThrown, true);
    }

}
public void sendMail() {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    Contact recipient = [SELECT id, OwnerId, Name FROM Contact
                         where Contact.MarketingContactId__c != NULL
                         and Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail = False
                         and Contact.record_updated__c = NULL LIMIT 1];
    ID ctId = recipient.OwnerId;
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'KI2Test'];
    User owner = [SELECT id, Name From User WHERE Id = : ctId LIMIT 1];

    mail.setTargetObjectId(recipient.id);
    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
    mail.setWhatId(recipient.id); //for mail merge             
    mail.setSenderDisplayName(owner.Name);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

    try {         
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] emailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
        recipient.UpdatedOnDate__c = system.today();
        recipient.record_updated__c = system.today();
        update recipient; // updates the record into the database
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('exception : ' + ex.getmessage());
    }
}
}
```

The testing class:

```
  @isTest//(SeeAllData=true)
private class SendMarketingMail_Test

{

static testmethod void execute() {
    //run every min   
    DateTime currentDateTime=System.now().addMinutes(1);
    String nextRun = String.valueOf(currentDateTime);
    String nextScheduleTime=String.valueof(currentDateTime.second()) +' '+String.valueof(currentDateTime.minute())+' '
        +String.valueof(currentDateTime.hour())+' '+String.valueof(currentDateTime.day())+' '
        +String.valueof(currentDateTime.month())+' ? '+String.valueof(currentDateTime.Year());

    test.StartTest();
    SendMarketingMail m = new SendMarketingMail ();
    String jobId = system.schedule('ApexMarketingEmails'+System.now().format(), nextScheduleTime, m);  
    CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId]; 
    System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
    System.assertEquals(nextRun,String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));
    sendMail();
    test.StopTest();
}


static testmethod void sendMail(){
    Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='John',LastName='Doe',Salutation='Mr.',Email='test@test.com',
                            OwnerId=UserInfo.getUserId(),HasOptedOutOfEmail=false,record_updated__c=NULL);
    insert c;
    System.debug('Contact='+c);
    MarketingContact__c mc = new MarketingContact__c(Name='Jane Doe',
                                                     Email__c = 'test@test.com'); 
    insert mc;
    System.debug('MarketingContact='+mc);
    c.MarketingContactId__c=mc.id;
    Id RecipientOwnerId=c.OwnerId;
    System.assertEquals(RecipientOwnerId,c.OwnerId);
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'KI2Test'];
    User owner =[SELECT id,Name From User WHERE Id=:RecipientOwnerId LIMIT 1 ];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'test@test.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);
    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
    mail.setWhatId(c.id);              
    mail.setSenderDisplayName(owner.Name);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
    Integer emailbefore = Limits.getEmailInvocations();       
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] emailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(new 
                                                                  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    system.assertNotEquals(emailbefore,Limits.getEmailInvocations(),'should have decreased');
    system.assertEquals(emailResult.get(0).Success,true);
    c.UpdatedOnDate__c=system.today();
    c.record_updated__c=system.today();
    update c;
}   
}
```

Comment: Where is the call of your schedulable class in your test?

Comment: test.StartTest();
    SendMarketingMail m = new SendMarketingMail () 

But maybe I'm doing something wrong here, quite inexperienced at the moment with apex development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, all of your code is too complicated, and your scheduled class is too fragile. The moment your exception is thrown, your scheduled class will die, never to run again.

For your unit test, you've missed the point of a unit test. Your second test method shouldn't be sending an email, but instead asking the scheduled class to send an email:

```
@isTest static void sendMail(){
    MarketingContact__c mc = new MarketingContact__c(Name='Jane Doe',
                                                     Email__c = 'test@test.com'); 
    insert mc;
    Contact c = new Contact(MarketingContactId__c=mc.id,FirstName='John',LastName='Doe',Salutation='Mr.',Email='test@test.com',
                            OwnerId=UserInfo.getUserId(),HasOptedOutOfEmail=false,record_updated__c=NULL);
    insert c;
    Test.startTest();
    System.schedule('TestJob'+Math.random(),'0 0 0 * * ?', new SendMarketingMail());
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

This code alone should net you more than 90% coverage, I'd imagine. Scheduled classes typically need to be examined internally, so you might modify your class to have some variables you can observe while testing:

```
global class SendMarketingMail Implements Schedulable {
    @TestVisible static Integer emailInvocations;
    @TestVisible static Boolean sentSuccessfully;
```

Assign the values in your sendEmail method, and then check them after calling Test.stopTest.

Also, you'll notice that the cron string I used was just hard-coded; for unit test purposes, this is okay, because Test.stopTest automatically calls your code.

Now, for the first part I mentioned, calculate your cron string as "0 "+nextFireMinute+" * * * ?" instead. This way, if your schedulable class fails to reschedule itself, it will resume an hour later rather than dying off completely.

Comment: Thank you for the great insights and explanation, everything worked like a charm!